# How can I combine with binding and custom visible binding for fadein/fadeout effects?

Tags: knockout.js

I want to use a custom binding handler (fadeVisible) to fadein/fadeout a forms. But I also want to use the with binding handler. If I use both together, the with binding handler set always display to none, before the fadeVisible handler can do this. So there is no fadeout effect. What is the right way to do this?

Example: 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eisenspalter/C2Z9f/4/)

```
<form data-bind="with:address, fadeVisible:address">
```

Comment: Any specific reason you want to use `with` here? If you remove it and make corresponding changes to the bindings, it will work.

Comment: In this special case I generate my knockout input fields programmatically and a input field should have no reference to the parent (address).

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. It makes sense why you want to do that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can emulate the `with` binding by setting `address` as the inner binding context of the element. Here's an updated binding called `fadeVisibleWith`...

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fadeVisibleWith = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        $(element).hide();

        var innerBindingContext = bindingContext.extend(value);
        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(innerBindingContext, element);
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        ko.unwrap(value) ? $(element).fadeIn() : $(element).fadeOut();
    }
};
```

And change the binding in the view...

```
<form data-bind="fadeVisibleWith:address">
    <p>
        <label>firstname</label>
        <input data-bind="value:firstName"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>lastname</label>
        <input data-bind="value:lastName"/>
    </p>
</form>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C2Z9f/10/

More details: [Creating custom bindings that control descendant bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the 'with' binding altogether from your code and directly bind your inputs with the address observable

```
<form data-bind="fadeVisible:address">
<p>
    <label>firstname</label>
    <input data-bind="value:address().firstName"/>
</p>
<p>
    <label>lastname</label>
    <input data-bind="value:address().lastName"/>
</p>
</form>
```

and **most importantly**, in your clear function, rather than setting address to null ,you must set it to empty to avoid any bindings error and actually clear it:

```
clear:function() {
    this.address('');
},
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarcastic/C2Z9f/9/)

Comment: I will not have a address reference in my Input fields.